# ImageUpload web api in asp.net mvc saved image to WebApi website instead of FrontEnd website directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I knew this is similar question of others but asking another way and need specific solution. I'm asking this question after my long research.

I have 2 websites one is asp.net web api & asp.net mvc web app and both are hosted like below:

> ASP.Net MVC Web API: http://example.com/api (Virtual Directory)
>
> ASP.Net MVC Web App: http://example.com

I have one api called "ProfileImageUpload" at `http://example.com/api/account/ProfileImageUpload`. When mobile developer try to upload profile image using this api, profile image uploaded to this path `http://example.com/api/images/profile/abc.jpg` but I want to save this image to this path `http://example.com/images/profile/abc.jpg`, not in web api website.

I have below code to doing image upload process:

```
    [Route("profileimageupload")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(PhotoInfoDO))]
    public IHttpActionResult ProfileImageUpload()
    {
        IHttpActionResult result = null;
        BaseResult<PhotoInfoDO> baseResult = new BaseResult<PhotoInfoDO>();

        PhotoInfoDO photo = new PhotoInfoDO();
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var loggedInUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            HttpPostedFileBase fileContent = new HttpPostedFileWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0]);
            if (fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileContent.FileName);
                var stream = fileContent.InputStream;
                string fileOrignalName = fileContent.FileName;
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileContent.FileName);
                string fileGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", fileGuid, fileExtension);
                string dbPath = "~/Images/Profile/";

                string imagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(dbPath);
                Common.createFolder(imagePath);

                bool HasUploaded = false;
                try
                {
                    
                    fileContent.SaveAs(imagePath + @"\" + fileName);
                    HasUploaded = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                long ProfileImageId = 0;

                try
                {
                    if (HasUploaded)
                    {
                        ProfileDO profile = _userServiceInstance.GetProfileByApplicationUserId(loggedInUserId);
                        ProfileImageId = profile.ProfileImageId;

                        MediaDO media = new MediaDO();
                        media.Path = dbPath;
                        media.FileName = fileGuid;
                        media.Extension = fileExtension;
                        media.OriginalFileName = fileOrignalName;
                        media.MimeType = mimeType;
                        media.Id = profile.ProfileImageId;
                        media.MediaTypeId = (long)MediaTypeEnum.UserProfileImage;

                        if (profile.ProfileImageId > 0)
                        {
                            Common.deleteProfileImages(profile.ProfileImageName);
                            _mediaServiceInstance.UpdateMediaById(media);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ProfileImageId = _mediaServiceInstance.AddMedia(media);
                        }
                        photo.ProfileImageId = ProfileImageId;
                        baseResult.Data = photo;
                        baseResult.Succeeded = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    base.LogElmahException(ex);
                    result = BadRequest("An error occurred while uploading image");
                    baseResult.Succeeded = false;
                }
            }
        }

        result = GetResult<PhotoInfoDO>(baseResult);
        return result;
    }
```

Can anyone please let me know what should be the image path?

Comment: dint look in depth,but where to save the immage is done using  HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(dbPath); .Isnt that all you have to change to save to different path ?

Comment: @RohithRajan It is giving me path `D:\Websites\Example\Api\Images\Profile\` but I need `D:\Websites\Example\Images\Profile\`. Api folder is virtual directory and hosted web api project.

Comment: This shows why it's not a good idea in general to store images in a relative folder. Assume that today they are running on the same server, but tomorrow, they might be split up for good reasons, and what now? Keep your images outside of your Web app. Now to solve your problem: I'd probably just make the Image Root Path an _AppSetting_... add `<add key="ImagePath" value="D:\Websites\Example\Images" />` to your Web.Config and your `imagePath` is becoming `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"]`

Comment: @thmshd I think I need to try this.

Comment: @thmshd Thanks for your hint. It works!